# "What am I doing wrong?"

Tags: java

Okay so this program is supposed to take a bet from a user, and print out some randomly generated numbers equal to that bet (ie. bet = 5, game prints num num num num num).
These generated numbers then have to be checked by a prime number method, and if any of the numbers end up being prime, the user wins 3* their bet. otherwise, they lose and are prompted to either play again or exit. oh and if their balance reaches 0 the game ends.

I have the bulk of what I need done, but there are things i can't get to work (i.e. print as many numbers as credits wagered) without breaking another aspect of my code (i.e. winning statement prints after finding a prime followed by the remaining non prime numbers).

I'm doing my best but I just can't figure it out.

What am I doing wrong?

This is my code so far:

```
    package isPrime;

    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class isPrime {
public static boolean isPrime(int number) {
    if (number <= 1) {
        return false;
    }
    if (number == 2) {
        return true;
    }
    if (number % 2 == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(number) + 1; i = i + 2) {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static int readNum(String prompt) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print(prompt);
    int number = input.nextInt();
    return number;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    boolean playing = true;

    int balance = 0;
    int bet = 0;
    int ans = 0;
    int i = 0;

    Random gen = new Random();
    balance = readNum("Enter a starting balance: ");
    System.out.println("Current balance: " + balance);
    while (playing) {

        bet = readNum("Enter a wager (0 to exit): ");
        balance -= bet;
        System.out.println("Current balance: " + balance);

        if (bet == 0) {
            playing = false;
            System.out.println("Thank you for playing PrimeGame!!");
        } else {

            for (i = bet; i > 0; i--) {
                int num = gen.nextInt(100000) + 1;

                System.out.print(num + "\t");
                if (isPrime(num)) {

                    System.out.println("You found a prime!!");
                    bet = bet * 3;
                    balance += bet;
                    System.out.println("You won " + bet);
                    System.out.println("Current balance: " + balance);
                    ans = readNum("Would you like to continue playing? (1:yes/0:no)");
                    if (ans == 0) {
                        playing = false;
                    }


                ans = readNum("Sorry, you lost. Would you like to play again? (1:yes/0:no)");
                    System.out.println("Current balance: " + balance);
                    if (balance == 0) {
                        System.out.println("Out of credits! Goodbye!");
                        playing = false;

                }

            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

I'm really stuck and this is worth 10%. ):

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: "but there are things i can't get to work" why can't you get them to work? what have you tried?

Comment: You need to take a stronger look at your `for (i = bet; i > 0; i--) {` loop.  The logic of "if any of n numbers is prime, win bet" is not implemented correctly here.  See if you can see why

Comment: I removed i = 0; as well as the else statement and it seems to be working properly if you win, but now I'm stuck on where to place my losing statement if they lose.

Comment: Be more specific and you might just figure out the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need to move your "Sorry, You Lost!" part out of the bet numbers generating `for` loop.

```
} else { 
    for (i = bet; i > 0; i--) {
        int num = gen.nextInt(100000) + 1;
        System.out.print(num + "\t");
        if (isPrime(num)) {
            // i = 0; // don't reset i here
            System.out.println("You found a prime!!");
            bet = bet * 3;
            balance += bet;
            System.out.println("You won " + bet);
            System.out.println("Current balance: " + balance);
            ans = readNum("Would you like to continue playing? (1:yes/0:no)");
            if (ans == 0) {
                playing = false;
            }
            break; // start from outer while loop again; (i is > 0 here)
        }
    }
    if (i == 0) { // i.e. no prime was generated
        ans = readNum("\nSorry, you lost. Would you like to play again? (1:yes/0:no)");
        System.out.println("Current balance: " + balance);
        if (balance == 0) {
            System.out.println("Out of credits! Goodbye!");
            playing = false;
        }
    }
}
```

***Output** :*

```
Enter a starting balance: 10
Current balance: 10
Enter a wager (0 to exit): 5
Current balance: 5
5290    12974   6400    97078   88412   
Sorry, you lost. Would you like to play again? (1:yes/0:no)1
Current balance: 5
Enter a wager (0 to exit): 3
Current balance: 2
60579   77951   You found a prime!!
You won 9
Current balance: 11
Would you like to continue playing? (1:yes/0:no)1
Enter a wager (0 to exit): 11
Current balance: 0
80100   76930   57505   64299   7932    18404   57852   79483   93270   24481   You found a prime!!
You won 33
Current balance: 33
Would you like to continue playing? (1:yes/0:no)0
```

*(PS: I made 23 dollars :)*

Comment: Thanks so much! You're a gentleman and a scholar.